# When making keras model having none-fixed input data size, is it possible to apply different layers depending on the size using lambda layer?

Tags: python, lambda, keras, jupyter

I am dealing with the Convolutional image model, which I convert and store the model to yaml file and then use it in code.
  The full size of input image is  256 * 256, but during the training, I train the model using a patch of size  128 * 128, and in the validation process I get the full size image. Therefore, the input size of the model is set to None.
  I would like to create a model by cropping only the middle part of the image, size of 64 * 64 from this input layer. At this time, the model have to crop the image in different length according to the input image size to produce the same output size(64*64). However, Is it possible to apply the if-else statement in my code? I would appreciate it if you could help me with the code.

```
patch = (None,None, 6)
x_input = Input(shape=patch)

def get_crop(x):
    from keras.layers import Cropping2D
    if x.get_shape().as_list()[1:3] ==[256,256]:
        return Cropping2D(cropping=(96,96))(x)
    else:
        return Cropping2D(cropping=(32,32))(x)

x_crop = Lambda(get_crop)(x_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You better ask in another StackExchange like CrossValidation but here is a short answer.

When dealing with varying image sizes, there’s two solutions. First is cropping the big image into multiple sub images and use a vote on the class you get for each sub image. The second solution, which is far better, is to have a fully Convolutional network. You can replace fully-connected blocks by big convolutions and use a global pooling for the classification layer (GlobalAveragePooling or MaxPooling).

Note that those solutions work only if the images you get are bigger. If there’s smaller images, the solution is to zoom the image or pad it. But better zoom.